# Decode URL Unix/Bash Command Line (without sed)

Tags: bash, unix, encoding, ascii, decode

I am scraping a website with curl and parsing out what I need.

The URLs are returned with Ascii encoded characters like

`GET v2.12/...?fields=&#123;fieldname_of_type_Tab&#125; HTTP/1.1`

How can I convert this to UTF-8 (char) directly from the command line (ideally something I can pipe `|` to) so that the result is...

`GET v2.12/...?fields={fieldname_of_type_Tab} HTTP/1.1`

EDIT: There are a number of solutions with `sed` but the regex that goes along with it is quite ugly. Since the provided answer leveraging perl is very clean I hope we can leave this question open

Comment: Would like to keep this as the answer is more elegant then related questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [html-entities](/questions/tagged/html-entities).

Decode like this using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ echo 'http://domain.tld/?fields=&#123;fieldname_of_type_Tab&#125' |
    perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_)'
```

### Output :

```
http://domain.tld/?fields={fieldname_of_type_Tab}
```

Comment: Wow, this is the most elegant solution I have come across for a command line conversion. Bonus for the fact it uses standard libraries